# $n \pmod k$ circuit

Tags: digital-circuits, modular-arithmetic

I wondered if, for a fixed integer $k ≥ 3$, how can I construct a circuit for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, that takes as input an n-bit integer $x$ and outputs whether 3 divides $k$?

Considering an n-bit integer as input:
e.g. $\ldots10101110$, where $a_0$ is the rightmost bit and $a_N$ the leftmost bit, $\bmod 3$ has a cycle of $2$:

$$(a_0 \times 2^0 + a_1 \times 2^1 + a_2 \times 2^2 + a_3 \times 2^3 + \ldots) \bmod 3\\ = a_0 \times 1 + a_1 \times (-1) + a_3 \times 1 + a4 \times (-1) \ldots$$

so it has a cycle of two, considering the remainder being either 1 or (-1).

How can I use this knowledge to construct a boolean circuit that checks for an n-bit integer as input the divisibility by 3?

Additionally:
Once solved for $k = 3$, how can I generalize this to any fixed k?
The idea behind this is to create a circuit whose sizes should be polynomial in n.

Important:
Please give hints only so I can figure it out myself!

Comment: Isn't it the coefficient alternating between ±1? The remainder should be 0 every once in a while.

Comment: if you are familiar with finite state automaton, you can try to design an automata that reads the binary encoding from the most significant bit to the least and ends in a state that corresponds to $n \mod k$. Now, you can "unfold" the automaton to make a circuit for each size $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, my knowledge of circuits is quite limited, so I will try to answer the question algorithmically. If You go through your bits from most to least significant, You could reconstruct Your number as follows:

```
number = 0

foreach bit in [a[n-1], a[n-2], ..., a[n]] do
  number = 2*number + bit
end foreach

return number
```

This can be done by a simple shift followed by an increment per iteration. But, of course, the number might be huge and we are only interested in the remainder. So instead we can can use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to only build the remainder:

```
remainder = 0

foreach bit in [a[n-1], a[n-2], ..., a[n]] do
  remainder = (2*number + bit) mod k
end foreach

return remainder
```

Since `2*remainder + bit <= 2*(k-1) + 1` we can replace the modulo operator by a comparison, conditonally followed by a subtraction:

```
remainder = 0

foreach bit in [a[n-1], a[n-2], ..., a[n]] do

  remainder = 2*number + bit

  if remainder >= k then
    remainder = remainder - k
  end if

end foreach

return remainder
```

And there You have it. For each bit in $a$ you would need:

- 1 Shift
- 1 Increment (e.g. via chain of ["flip-flops"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)))
- 1 Comparison
- 1 Conditional Subtraction (e.g. via Ripple-Carry-Adder using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of $k$)

That should take around $\mathcal{O}\left(\left\lceil\log_2\left(2k-1\right)\right\rceil\right)$ logic gates per bit in $a$.

In practice there are of course much more efficient solutions than that. For division algorithms, I can recommend the book [Modern Computer Arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4710). Everything You learn there should be applicable to circuits as well, but You will have to think much more parallel in circuit design, I presume.

For reference, here is a Scala implementation of the algorithm:

```scala
def mod( n: BigInt, k: Int ): Int =

  require(n >= 0)
  require(k >  1)

  var rem = 0L

  var i = n.bitLength
  while i > 0 do
    i -= 1
    rem *= 2
    if n.testBit(i) then rem += 1
    if rem >= k     then rem -= k
  end while

  assert(rem >= 0)
  assert(rem <  k)
  return rem.toInt

end mod
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the detailed explanation! I spun up some code for it and noticed that this approach indeed works for k=3. Do you know how to do the same for k = 11 for example? This approach doesn't work for all fixed k's.

Comment: It *should* work for every $k >= 2$ if I am not mistaken...

Comment: Indeed. Something was off in my previous code. I updated it and posted it here too. Thanks again for your help, I marked it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some JS code that performs the n mod k operations. To visualize I generate all 8-bit representations and let them run through the function to output a truth table, outputting True if divisible by k and False otherwise. For higher bit-inputs one can adapt the code.

```
function mod(n, k) {
  if (n < 0 || k <= 1) {
    throw new Error("Invalid input: n must be non-negative and k must be greater than 1");
  }

  let rem = 0n; // Use BigInt for arbitrary precision arithmetic

  let i = n.toString(2).length; // Bit length of n
  while (i > 0) {
    i -= 1;
    rem *= 2n;
    if (n & (1n << BigInt(i))) rem += 1n;
    if (rem >= BigInt(k)) rem -= BigInt(k);
  }

  if (rem < 0n || rem >= BigInt(k)) {
    throw new Error("Assertion failed: Invalid remainder value");
  }

  return Number(rem);
}

// Generate all 8-bit combinations
const allCombinations = Array.from({ length: 256 }, (_, i) => BigInt(i));

// Set the value of k
const kValue = 13;

// Iterate over the combinations and check divisibility by k
const divisibilityResults = allCombinations.map(combination => mod(combination, kValue) === 0);

console.log(divisibilityResults);
```

Thanks to @DirkT for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Given a 3 bit number, we can find a 2 bit number with the same remainder modulo 3. That means we map 0 to 7 to 0, 1, 2, 0 or 3, 1, 2, 0 or 3, and 1. So we take the number xyz and create a circuit C that outputs y’, z’ as follows: If x=0 then y’ = y, z’ = z. If x = 1 then with 4 modulo 3 = 1 we map 1yz to 01 if y = z and to 1y if y ≠ z.

For n >= 3 bits, we use this to transform the first 3 bits to two bits and are left with n-1 bits. Then we feed these two bits and the fourth bit into an identical circuit, get n-2 bits, and so on until we are left with just two bits. At that point xy is divisible by 3 if and only if x=y.

If you want to build super fast hardware then the problem is that you have a chain of n of these circuits in sequence, taking O(n) steps. You can reduce this to O(log n). Use this method for n <= 4. For n <= 8 transform the upper and lower 4 bits into 2 bits each in parallel, then take the resulting 4 bits and handle them as before. For n = 16, split x into 2 x 8 bits, for n = 32 use 2 x 16 bit, for n = 64 use 2 x 32 bits and so on. This takes O(log n) sequential steps.

How many circuits C do we need? n = 4 -> 2 circuits C. n = 8 -> 2x2, plus 2, = 6 circuits. n = 16 -> 2x6, plus 2, = 14 circuits, n = 32 -> 30 circuits, n = 64 -> 62 circuits C. That’s what we need anyway, so the fast circuit for large n doesn’t actually need more hardware.

How to build such a circuit: First build a circuit A which outputs (x = y) for inputs x and y. This is (y AND z) OR (NOT y AND NOT z). Now "01 for y=z, or 1y for y!=z" is done by a circuit which outputs (A AND 0) OR (NOT A AND 1) = NOT A, and another that outputs (A AND 1) OR (NOT A AND y) = A or y, call the circuit with these two outputs B and B'. And finally you have (NOT x AND y) OR (x AND b), and (NOT x AND z) OR (x AND b').

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is a neat way of how to reduce the size of the circuit. However, I tried to build a circuit from your idea and had issues realizing this. I simply don't know how I can translate the "if x=0, then output = yz, if x=1, then output is either 01 for y=z, or 1y for y!=z". How do I realize this approach?